# c programming speed up mysql_query

Tags: mysql, c

I have 6530 lines of data to query and insert into my database. Is there hopefully a way to speed this up? This took 7 minutes to do.

column_counter is the size of my lines. I am using snprintf to convert my values into a string so mysql_query will accept it.

I updated the code. It now disables autcommit. I removed the memset. I figured I needed that to avoid segmentation faults. Thank you for all the suggestions.

```
mysql_autocommit(con, 0);
for(i = 0; i < column_counter; i++)
{
    snprintf(querystring, sizeQuerystring,
    "INSERT INTO earnings " \
    "VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d)",
    column1[i], column2[i], column3[i], column4[i]);
    if (mysql_query(con, querystring)) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Insert failed\n");
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",mysql_error(con));
        finish_with_error(con);
    }
    //memset(querystring, 0, 256);
    if(i - 1 == column_counter)
    {
        printf(" finished with earnings.csv \n", column_counter);
    }
}
mysql_commit(con);
```

Comment: Normally, putting the Insert into a transaction , increases the speed dramatically. I don't know how this works for MySQL. When you need an index, try to create it when all Inserts are done.

Comment: @harandk That one for loop takes 7 minutes. Not sure what you are saying to do.

Comment: regarding: `finish_with_error(con);` should exit or return, not continue to run the loop.

Comment: the statement: `memset(querystring, 0, 256);` is completely unnecessary as the call to `snprintf()` will overlay the value.

Comment: from the posted code, it seems that `sizeQueryString` and 256 are the same.  So the `256 is a 'magic' number.  Suggest using 'sizeQueryString` rather than 256

Comment: @user3629249 I removed the memset. I figured I needed that to avoid segmentation faults.

Answer (score 1):

> I have 6530 lines of data to query and insert into my database. Is
>   there hopefully a way to speed this up? This took 7 minutes to do.

There are at least two distinct and compatible changes you can make to how you are using the MySQL API:

- Since all the insert statements you are executing have the same form, and differ only in the values inserted, you should be able to create a [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html) that you can then re-use.  This saves significant time in such cases because the SQL only needs to be parsed once.
- Because I see no call to `mysql_commit()`, I assume you are operating in autocommit mode.  It is often more efficient to batch a bunch of statements together in the same transaction, and then to commit them all at once.  This requires [disabling autocommit mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-autocommit.html) and performing a manual commit at the end (i.e. after the loop terminates).

Additionally, although it's unlikely to be contributing much to the overall time, you can get rid of the `memset()` at the end of the loop.  It's pointless, because you're just going to overwrite the same bytes during the next iteration.

Comment: I disabled the autocommit mode. I removed the `memset()`. Any chance you can help with the prepared statements? I am having trouble understanding the documentation.

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987, the [docs for `mysql_stmt_execute()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html) contain a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

Needs a little more coding, but multiple rows in a single insert command like this would bring huge performance increase:

INSERT INTO earnings
VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d),
VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d),
.
.